# Не получается протестировать метод, как написать заглушку?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, groovy

Итак есть метод

```
def getYahooFinanceDataAndSaveToDB() {
    String url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL+GOOG+MSFT&f=nab'
    Date dt = new java.util.Date()
    String content = url.toURL().getText();
    //  render content
    ArrayList<String> list = content.split("\n");
    for (String i : list) {
        def count=Counter.get('QN_ID')
        assert 'QN_ID' == count.name
        count.value+=1
        //  render count.value
        MyData date = new MyData(Id:count.value ,Data: i, RecordCreateDate: dt)
        date.save()
        count.save()
    }
}
```

На него написал примерно такой тест с запуском потоков

```
def "Run 10 concurrent threads that call the method 50 times each"() {
    given:
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<10;i++){
        Thread x = new Thread()
        x.run()
        for (int j=0; j<50;j++){
        def service = new YahooReaderService();
        def meth = service.yahooFinanceDataAndSaveToDB
        count+=1
}
    }
    when:
assertEquals(count, 250)

    then: "true"
}
```

Ругается на строку def count=Counter.get('QN_ID') которая запрашивает данные из бд

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
yahooreader.Counter.get() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: get(java.io.Serializable), getId(), grep(),
getAt(java.lang.String), grep(java.lang.Object), wait()
```

Как правильно написать Mosk заглушку на запись и чтение из базы в данном случае?